# Where can I find Windows Live Style comment box for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, richtextbox, comments

I am looking for a nice comment box, instead of creating something with textbox and a button. Windows live photos has a nice comment box under each photo, it is one line with a small triangle on left bottom , which makes it look like dialog box from comic books. It also has send button on the right inside the box so no additional buttons. How can I do something like this ?

Comment: Maybe post an image so we know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy to find ready-to-go templates for input controls, so why not create your own? You can start by reading [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). All you need is learn the basics of templating and then you'll be able to reproduce the style you want.